# Restrict one page of a wiki (or site pages)

Tags: 2013, permissions, wiki, sitepages

In 2007 you could call out permissions for 1 object in a document library thus restricting a page in a wiki or document library

In 2013 I dont see any options for that level of granularity, How can i limit a page to just owners group for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a 'Page' tab in the ribbon interface.  On here is a section labeled 'Manage' that has the following options:

- Edit Properties
- Rename Page
- Page History
- Page Permissions
- Delete Page

The 'Page Permissions' button allows you to stop inheriting permissions for that page and set your own custom permissions.

Comment: Seems simple I guess they just moved it around where I wasn't expecting